# Eclipse Juno does not restore package explorer after closing all files

Tags: windows, eclipse

When I close the last file in a maximized file panel, I used to have eclipse auto restore (show) the package explorer for me, that does not happen in Juno.

It used to work on older versions of eclipse. For Juno, It works on the Java EE perspective, but not on the Java perspective.

Is it a bug, or is there a configuration that can fix this for me?